# REST Assured - Generic List deserialization

Tags: java, arrays, json, deserialization, rest-assured

Let's say I have a Java `Person` class:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    String email;
}
```

With REST Assured, you can deserialize this JSON object

```
{"name":"Bob", "email":"bob@email.com"}
```

to a Java `Person` instance using

```
Person bob = given().when().get("person/Bob/").as(Person.class);
```

How does one use REST Assured to deserialize this JSON array

```
[{"name":"Bob", "email":"bob@email.com"}, 
 {"name":"Alice", "email":"alice@email.com"}, 
 {"name":"Jay", "email":"jay@email.com"}]
```

into a `List<Person>`? For example, this would be handy:

```
List<Person> persons = given().when().get("person/").as(...);
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I found a way to achieve what I wanted:

```
List<Person> persons = given().when().get("person/").as(Person[].class);
```

**UPDATE:** Using Rest-Assured 1.8.1, looks like cast to List is not supported anymore. You need to declare and object array like this:

```
Person[] persons = given().when().get("person/").as(Person[].class);
```

Comment: did not work for me, with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod.getParameterType(I) . Is there any prerequisites for this stuff?

Comment: Its working perfectly for me. I am using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.1

Comment: my version is 2.4.1. so that may be the reason.

Answer (score 35):

To extract a Java List, and not an Array, from a JSON API response, you just have to remember to use `jsonPath` rather than `as`:

```
List<Person> persons = given()
        .when()
        .get("/person")
        .then()
        .extract()
        .body()
        // here's the magic
        .jsonPath().getList(".", Person.class);
```

Your json path can point to anywhere you expect to have a list of json objects in your body. in this example (and working for your question) it just points to the json root.

sidenode: rest-assured is internally using jackson for deserialization (for `.jsonPath` as well as `.as`)

Answer (score 29):

for those who found out that accepted answer does not work anymore.

```
    List<Entity> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list = given()
            .contentType(CONTENT_TYPE)
        .when()
            .get(getRestOperationPath())
        .then()
            .extract().body().as(list.getClass());
```

hopefully, you understand that getRestOperationPath is returning rest operation path; and CONTENT_TYPE is placeholder for your content type (application/json for example)

upd: checked different versions, behavior differs depending on version, so you might want to try different approaches

upd2: **cleaner solution** was pointed by @Arigion in comments:

```
to use .extract().body().jsonPath().getList(".", Entity.class);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.  Clean, simple, and the most up-to-date response.

Comment: it is better to use .extract().body().jsonPath().getList(".", Entity.class); 
You'd get an unchecked warning otherwise.

Comment: @Arigion included that into answer :) please tell me if you made Answer with that so I can link it; I didn't find it.

Answer (score 22):

We can now use `TypeRef` much as it's possible to do it with the JsonPath library:

```java
List<Person> persons = given().when().get("person/")
    .as(new TypeRef<List<Person>>() {});
```

As with https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#what-is-returned-when - the anonymous inner class `new TypeRef<List<Person>>() {}` gets around type erasure and captures the type information enough that the framework can access the raw type - `List` in this case. The internal generic type - `Person` - is a safe cast that can be made under the circumstances.

Comment: Shorter-yet syntax also worked great for me: `.as(new TypeRef<>() {})` thanks to `import io.restassured.mapper.TypeRef;` even with old 2019 `'io.rest-assured', version: '3.3.0'`

Comment: @MarkHu that's nice!

Answer (score 13):

You could also do this if you were interested in using "expect()"

```
expect().
 body("get(0).firstName", equalTo("Mike")).
when().
 get("person/");
```

This was my case

Answer (score 8):

If anyone's still looking.
Using Java 1.8 and RestAssured 2.9
the solution is really simple and it does not throw "Unchecked Warning".

```
return Arrays.asList(given()
            .when()
            .get("restPath")
            .then()
            .extract()
            .response()
            .body()
            .as(Player[].class));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable with JsonPath, i would suggest using any java serialization/de-serialization using GSON or Jackson.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want to map

```
[{"name":"Bob", "email":"bob@email.com"}, 
 {"name":"Alice", "email":"alice@email.com"}, 
 {"name":"Jay", "email":"jay@email.com"}]
```

to java object.

Now while calling the endpoint you can directly map to the Person list as shown below

```
List<Person> personList = given().when().get("person/").as(Person[].class);
```

Note the Person class should remain same i.e. no need to do any modification for the person class.

```
public class Person{
 String name;
 String email;
}
```

Comment: The type `PersonArray` has a _field_ `personList` which is not present in the above data.

Comment: @AshleyFrieze Thanks for the comment, I have added additional wrapper. I have modified my solution

Answer (score -2):

This would be helpful, works with current version of rest assured.

```
@Test
    public void apostUser() {
        Map<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put("User_Id", "xyx1111");
        user.put("First_Name", "KS");
        user.put("Designation", "DR");

        given()
        .contentType("application/json")
        .body(user)
        .when().post("URI").then()
        .statusCode(200);
    }
```